# Include checkbox validator on page with two forms

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, validation, checkbox

I have a payment page. At the top of the page I have a standard div with some "Please confrim you agree to the T's & C's" text and a checkbox.

Underneath that there are two separate forms each with a different payment option/button "Pay by cheque" and "pay by card".

Is it possible to validate a checkbox on both form submit buttons as the user can pick the payment option?

Note: The div is outside of both forms. I don't think nested forms are strictly legal.

I'm also using Foundation 6 Framework, considering using the abide, but I'm stuck as to how to validate if the checkbox is checked for both submit buttons.

Any help appreciated.

[image: forms]

Comment: bind a onsubmit to form 1 and form 2 which checks if the checkbox is checked in form 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Override default's form submit, check if the checkbox is checked and then submit the form.

Example code:

```
$(function(){
  $("#form1, #form2").on('submit', function(){
    if($("#terms:checked").length) {
      $(this).submit(); //if checked, submit form
    }
    else {
      alert('Please accept the terms'); //else show form errors
    }
    return false;
  });
});
```

If you use jQuery validation plugin you can use $("#terms").valid() instead of 
$("#terms:checked").length.

Here is a simple example I created for you: [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jcwu2y4v/)

Answer (score 0):

If you're not using external library to validate, it's easy to do the next:

```
<input type="submit" value="Pay" onclick="return checkIfAgreed();">
<script>
    function checkIfAgreed() {
         // get the check box dom and make sure it's checked
         // then return true if OK or false if not;
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

#### About validate a checkbox on multiple forms

Sure you can. Check the term input `checked` property and, if not `checked`, `return false` to the form submit event.

```
// The name of your Terms input
var $terms = $('[name="terms"]');

$('form').submit(function(){
  if ( !$terms.prop('checked') ) {
    console.log('Terms not checked');
    return false;
  }
});
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/84ewbyxh/2/)

---

#### About nested forms

> Note: I don't think nested forms are strictly legal.

You absolutely right.

From the html5 working draft:

> #### 4.10.3 The `form` element
>
> **Content model:**
>   Flow content, but ***with no form element descendants***.

[Answer from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/379610/can-you-nest-html-forms)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for the quick replies. Having read everyone's answer and reviewed a similar checkbox validation solution I also found the below to work:
Not sure what solution is best... but hey, they work! Thank you all :-)

```js
     function checkIfAgreed() {
      if (!document.getElementById('agreeTerms').checked){
       alert('Please confirm you have read and understood the acceptance conditions');
      return false;}
    }
```

```html
    <input type="checkbox" id="agreeTerms">
    
    <form>
      <input type="submit" value="Option 1" onclick="return checkIfAgreed();">
    </form>
    
    <form>
      <input type="submit" value="Option 2" onclick="return checkIfAgreed();">
    </form>
```